# Understanding how this grepl() function in R works

Tags: r, grepl

I have this sample `grepl()` code that differentiates between male and females name. The following code is given and it works but I am unable to understand how it works.

```
name = c("Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",
         "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)")

grepl("\\(.*?\\)", name)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I mean.. _Aren't they all duplicates_ wicter ? Just mark them all dups..

Answer (score 0):

The matching is based on the presence of `(`, zero or more characters (`.*`) that follows it and followed by a closing `)`).  Here, it assumes that the female names have the braces.  We can also match based on the `Mrs.`

```
grepl("\\bMrs\\.", name)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't differentiate between male and female names.

`"\\(.*?\\)"` is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). It is a powerful way of searching for patterns in large texts (like `CTRL + F`)

`grepl("\\(.*?\\)", name)` searches for an element in `names` that conforms to having an opening bracket `(`, followed by a number of characters, followed by a closing bracket `)`.

So this regular expression does *not* distinguish between male and female names, it distinguishes between elements with `( .. something something .. )` and elements without such a pattern.